# Which charset should i use for multilingual website?

Tags: html, character-encoding, multilingual

My website is going to support multi languages , as of now english , french, chinese..

So i used the charset `charset=iso-8859-1` but the chinese character are rendered, then i changed them to `charset=UTF-8` but the accent character in french are not displayed.

What's the best charset definition for multilingual websites?

And what's the best in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UTF-8 unless your primary content is targeted at Asia, in which case use UTF-16. (They contain the same set of characters, but -8 is generally more efficient for Western characters and -16 for Eastern characters)

You have to make sure the data is encoded in the encoding you specify. Just telling a web server to claim that the data is UTF-8 is not enough.

See also:

- [Choosing & applying a character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings)
- [Setting encoding in web authoring applications](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-setting-encoding-in-applications)
- [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

Comment: While UTF-16 is smaller than UTF-8 for *plain text* files in Asian languages, HTML documents will have a disproportionately high number of ASCII characters because of all the tags and attributes.