# HTML and PHP cURL response utf-8 encoding problem

Tags: php, html, curl, utf-8

Am getting HTML from cURL in TWO websites.

> SITE 1:
> https://xperia.sony.jp/campaign/360RA/?s_tc=somc_co_ext_docomo_360RA_banner
>
> SITE 2:
> https://www.fidelity.jp/fwe-top/?utm_source=outbrain&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=similar-gdw&utm_content=FS001&dicbo=v1-b6eb7c5f86a6978bba74e3703a046886-00d8ad90c4cb65b2bdcc239bcccf5ec378-mnrtcytfgu4toljwgjrwgljumu4wmljzg5tgkljxgzsdgzbqmyzwenbsgy

My cURL looks like:

```
$ua= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0 SeaMonkey/2.33.1";     
$options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
                CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true, 
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings 
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $ua, // who am i
                
                       
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10, // timeout on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10, // timeout on response
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
                CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
        
        $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            $content = curl_exec($ch);

         //Use xPath or str_get_html($content) to parse
```

The FIRST URL opens perfectly encoded and shows characters as expected

```
Exaple: $title_string = $html->find("title",0)->plaintext shows the <title> tag text and characters well encoded
```

The *SECOND URL* shows *SQUARE BOXES* `¤ããªãããi��Ɨ�` . But when you do `utf8_decode( $title_string)`, then this *SECOND URL* will show well encoded characters as expected.

The problem is, when you use `utf8_decode( $title_string)`, the *FIRST URL* now shows *SQUARE BOXES*.

Is there a way to have a universal way of solving this issue?

I have tried

```
$charset=  mb_detect_encoding($str);
    if( $charset=="UTF-8" ) {
        return utf8_decode($str);
    }
    else {
        return $str;
    }
```

Seems both Strings are being encoded as UTF-8 by cURL. One works, the other shows square boxes.

I have also tried

> [php curl response encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837892/php-curl-response-encoding)

> [Strange behaviour when encoding cURL response as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473317/strange-behaviour-when-encoding-curl-response-as-utf-8)

> [Replace unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959626/replace-unicode-character)

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

> [Which charset should i use for multilingual website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498306/which-charset-should-i-use-for-multilingual-website)

> [French and Chinese characters are not appearing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336173/french-and-chinese-characters-are-not-appearing-correctly)

And many more

I have spend critical hours trying to solve this. Any idea is welcome

Comment: _xperia_ site contains explicit `<head> <meta charset="utf-8"> …` while _fidelity_ does not?

Comment: a way to satisfactorily encode both to UTF-8?? T-you!

Comment: [`CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'UTF-8'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489894/3439404)?

Comment: I still get this see link  https://ctrlv.link/CV8A with adding  `CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'UTF-8'`

Comment: CURLOPT_ENCODING is about the content-encoding, so totally unrelated here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both pages are UTF-8 encoded, and cURL returns that as is. The problem is the following processing; assuming that libxml2 is involved, it tries to guess the encoding from `<meta>` elements, but if there are none, it assumes ISO-8859-1. It can be forced to assume UTF-8, if an UTF-8 BOM ("\xEF\xBB\xBF") is preprended to the HTML.

Comment: This SAVED my skin. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @cmb in the answer above, for those who would like to see my Final code in full details. Here you go

```
$url = "https://stackoverflow.com/
 
$html = str_get_html($url);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Yeah if you are so worried about using @ with warnings

    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML("\xEF\xBB\xBF$html"); // This is where and how you put the BOM
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';
    $metas = $xpath->query($query);
    $rmetas = array();

    foreach ($metas as $meta) {
        $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
        $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        $rmetas[$property] = $content;
    }

    var_dump($rmetas);
```

Hope it helps someone in the same peril.